# curl request with headers in PHP

Tags: php, post, curl

I want to make a cURL request to a URL along with the following headers :

**'Content-Type: application/json',
'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXX'**

I have the following code :

```
<?php

$post_url = "https://api.interlinkexpress.com/user/?action=login";

$curl = curl_init($post_url);

$headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXX'
        );
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username":"Password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($post_data) );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
$post_response = curl_exec($curl); 

?>
```

it is showing the result as :

> Client sent a Bad Request

which is the 'Authorization...' line under the $header array

Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

Comment: Try adding some User-Agent to headers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

problem is in header.It needs to be fixed.authorization will e whole string like this:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXX'
    );
```

let me give you a full example of curl:

```
 function CurlSendPostRequest($url,$request)
    {
        $authentication = base64_encode("username:password");

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $options = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,         // return web page
                CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,        // don't return headers
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,         // follow redirects
               // CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "utf-8",           // handle all encodings
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,         // set referer on redirect
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,          // timeout on connect
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 20,          // timeout on response
                CURLOPT_POST            => 1,            // i am sending post data
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $request,    // this are my post vars
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,            // don't verify ssl
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,        //
                CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
                    "Authorization: Basic $authentication",
                    "Content-Type: application/json"
                )

        );

        curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
        //echo $curl_errno;
        //echo $curl_error;
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: I did that. It then told me that there is some issue in the :

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "scally":"scally");

I removed it as I already encoded the Username and Passowrd in Header.

Now it says : Client sent a bad request.

Comment: Is there any sample code for which I can send a a POST request to the URL along with the 2 above Headers.

Comment: yes. you can set username password using base64 encoded of authorization header or CURLOPT_USERPWD. for CURLOPT_USERPWD,  you also need to put username and password in same string sperated by ':' and for special character you need to do url encode for username and password for CURLOPT_USERPWD.if that does not work the problem is elsewhere I guess

Comment: Can you please procide the exact way how I should write the Base64 encoded Username and Password ?

Comment: I have added on more code in current revision.please check that.

Comment: can you please check the code? in this way authorization header works.it does not work that means problem is in another place.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the above provided code. However, i don't know what's that '$request'. Please help me how can I call the function mentioned.

Comment: $request is the post request that sent.you need api documentation to do what you need to do.it sole depends on api documentation.

Comment: There is no API Documentation. Actually there is no REQUEST. I just want to login using the credentials. The username and Password are teh credentials that I use, which are to be Base 64 encoded. Shall I remove the $request ?

Comment: actually an POST request must have request body

Comment: like you can add this as a request body:

$request = ('action'=>'login'); $requestBody = http_build_query($request);

Comment: I got the solution. In first lien I did the following : 
**function CurlSendPostRequest($url,$request="")**
and the same had been implemented. I really appreciate the help and Thanks a ton, for teh clean cURL code.

Answer (score 0):

500 Error typically suggests that the error is on the server side. You can probably try to emulate your request ( I would personally recommend using [Advanced ReST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo), which is a google-chrome app), to verify whether this is the case.

Comment: You are right. I just uploaded the file on other server and found the new error. Actually in the previous server, the Error-listing was not enabled thus ot might have re-directed to 500 Error. Thanks for the info though, and also appreciate your time. But my question is still un-answered.