# How to get only the body of the response in a Curl request in php

Tags: php, curl

I'm a beginner in Curl and I'm having issues with the value that I get from `curl_exec()`.
I'm connecting to a bank's server and want to get only the array from the server, but `curl_exec()` returns the whole string with the header and the array. How can I make it only send the array?

```
    <?php
$url = 'https://the-url.com';
$auth = 'authentication key';
$method ='POST';
$grant = 'grant_type=client_credentials';

$crl = curl_init();
$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: Basic '.$auth;
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $grant);


$rest = curl_exec($crl);

if ($rest === false)
{
    print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl));
}
curl_close($crl);
$data = json_decode($rest, true);
echo $rest;
?>
```

this outputs

```
HTTP/2 200 a: x content-type: application/json content-length: 345 date: Tue, 21 Sep 2021 12:26:47 GMT strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000{array}
```

when I want it to output just `{array}` so I can use `json_decode()` on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

to

```
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
```

Since you are expecting a json response.

Comment: I just tried it and it sent this: `HTTP/2 415 a: x content-type: application/json content-length: 133 date: Tue, 21 Sep 2021 12:41:11 GMT strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000 {"error_code":415,"error_message":"Unsupported media type, please visit API documentation page","information_link":"","details":null}`

Comment: This might help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064737/curl-request-with-headers-in-php

Comment: thank you! the problem was that I had `CURLOPT_HEADER = true`, which is why it was returning the whole thing, to fix it, I just had to set `CURLOPT_HEADER = false`